# Pointing EC2 instance to a directory on a domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

There are 2 EC2 instances running:

1. Windows Server 2012 - ASP.NET application
2. Linux - Wordpress Blog

The ASP application is on `domain.com/`

How can you point Wordpress to `domain.com/blog/` instead of `blog.domain.com`?

You can use any AWS feature.

Comment: why down-vote? at least explain what's wrong or point in the right direction.

Comment: The question is not clear. Try read your own question again and define the meaning of "pointing".

Comment: Despite a certain lack of rigurosity I think the question is clear enough. Up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

The most cost-efficient way I see to do it is by using the resources you have already. The basic idea is to point your Route53 record to one of the EC2 instances and use "something" (I'll explain this later) to redirect the requests from this EC2 to the other. It can be either from the Windows one to the Linux one or the other way around. For example:

Let's say you point your domain (`domain.com`) to the Linux EC2 instance. Let's name this one as `EC2-Linux`. Install the afore mentioned "something", I'd suggest `nginx` in this box. If you aren't familiar with ngnix, [check out their how-to's](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/).

Once you have `nginx` up and running, create a config file with a redirect rule like (note: I haven't tested this conf file):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    # Redirect blog request to itself
    location /blog {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80/$uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    }

    # Redirect the rest of the traffic to the other EC2 instance
    location /* {
        proxy_pass http://<EC2-Win IP>:80/$uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    }
}
```

You surely need to fine tune `nginx` and your applications to make it work, but I think the idea answers your question without needing to add more AWS resources to your stack.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create CloudFront distribution with /blog/ origin to the Linux server, and default to ASP.Net, which means everything other than /blog/ will go to ASP.Net.

Comment: Could you provide more details please? I couldn't figure out how to do that. I am familiar with cloudfront for making CDNs, but how can I use it to point to a folder?

Comment: Check Path Pattern: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern